# Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings. Angular2

Tags: angular

I get such error

> Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.

Here is my code

```
styleUrls:[
    "../../styles/login.component.styles.scss"
],
```

When I have them declared in the same way but, the file with styles exist in the same directory as the component the problem does not occur.

Comment: How about `styleUrls:[
    require("../../styles/login.component.styles.scss")
]`?

Comment: I get **Cannot find module "."**

Comment: I really don't see why this doesn't work, I even tested it in an angular project and it worked. I suspect there is something else wrong. do you get any other error messages? do this error come up when you use `ng serve` or when you build for production? is this an angular cli generated project? did you eject to generate the webpack.config file?

Comment: When I start by npm start, project just do not start, and this error appear in console. I have only this error.

Comment: When i set it like that it's working `styleUrls:[
        "./login.component.styles.scss"
    ],`

Answer (score 4):

**I [filed an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7245) for this,** which was triaged as `workaround 2: non-obvious`, `priority: 2 (required)`, `severity 3: broken`.

I was struggling with something similar while porting an existing angular 2 *beta-6* application to angular-cli 1.2.6; we use SCSS throughout.

*Caveat:* I do not know if the modifications I was required to make (outlined below) are artifacts from our legacy architecture, are limitations of the framework, or are something else, but they worked for me.

After much debugging and trying recommendations from various sources, I discovered that some webpack magic causes the compiled CSS resulting from a file reference in a `@Component`'s `styleUrl[]` *which is also in* `.angular-cli.json`'s `styles[]` array to be interpreted as `{}`. The expected output is a string representation of the compiled SCSS file as CSS.

This will then cause `angular-compiler`'s `assertArrayOfStrings()` call to `throw` with none other than `Expected '" + identifier + "' to be an array of strings.`

I had to make the following changes to my application to get it to work:

1. Global stylesheet references that were `app.component`'s `styleUrls[]` array must be moved to `.angular-cli.json`'s `app[0].styles[]` array.
2. `app.component`'s `styleUrls[]` array should be empty.
3. `app.component`'s `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` meta-decorator can be removed.
4. Stylesheets which are referenced in `.angular-cli.json`'s `app[0].styles[]` array must not be referenced in any Component's `styleUrls[]` decorator.

Comment: It was #4 that was ruining my day. Thank you!

Comment: @TylerMerle Sweet! Sadly that bug is still open. Maybe I'll make it a [hacktoberfest](https://hacktoberfest.digitalocean.com/) goal.